# MPMoviePlayerController crash when start play a video on iOS 6

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play video. In my app I am playing video(s) that are in the app, using the standard `MPMoviePlayerController` class. It works fine on iOS 7 and 8

The first time around around this works great, however after watching 1 video if you try and watch something else the app crashes on `MPMoviePlayerController`'s play method with the error:

> : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
>
> *** -[MPMoviePlayerController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e5718b0

I can not figure out why this is happening.

Here is my code:

**AFPlayerViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController;

- (id)initWithContentURL:(NSString*)movieUrl
         andSubtitlePath:(NSString*)subPath
          withTypeServer:(NSString*)serverType
                withName:(NSString*)name
           withEpisodeId:(NSString*)episodeId
              withFilmId:(NSString*)filmId
            withDuration:(NSInteger)targetDuration
              withSeason:(NSString*)seasonId;
```

**AFPlayerViewController.m**

```
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (_movieURL) {
        self.playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: _movieURL];
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.f;
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

        [self.playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

        [self.view addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];
        [NSLayoutConstraint alightTopBotLeftRight:self.playerViewController.view inView:self.view];

        [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer play];

        [self receiveNotificationPlayerViewController];
    }
}

- (void)receiveNotificationPlayerViewController {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(durationAvailable:)
                                                 name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(sourceTypeAvailable:)
                                                 name:MPMovieSourceTypeAvailableNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(readyForDisplay:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didFinishAVideo:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];
}

- (void) durationAvailable: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"1");
}

- (void) loadStateDidChange: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"2");
    if ([self.playerViewController.moviePlayer loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                       object:nil];
    }
}

- (void) playbackStateDidChange: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"3");
    switch (self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.playbackState) {
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward:
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward:
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused: {
            NSLog(@"pause");
        }
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped: {
            NSLog(@"stop");
        }
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted:{
            NSLog(@"interrupted");
        }
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying: {
            NSLog(@"playing");
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) sourceTypeAvailable: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"4");
}

- (void) readyForDisplay: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"5");
}

- (void)orientationDidChange: (NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"6");
}

- (void)didFinishAVideo:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self removeNotification];
}

- (void)removeNotification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMovieSourceTypeAvailableNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.playerViewController.moviePlayer];
}
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AFPlayerViewController *player;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
+ (AppDelegate *)shareInstance{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (UIViewController *)currentVisibleController{
    id rootController = self.window.rootViewController;

    if ([rootController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootController;
        return navigationController.topViewController;
    }

    if ([rootController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        UITabBarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)rootController;
        id topViewController = [tabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabbarController.selectedIndex];
        if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *navi = (UINavigationController *)topViewController;

            return navi.topViewController;
        }

        return topViewController;
    }
    return self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

When I'd like to play a video:

```
[AppDelegate shareInstance].player = [[AFPlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:link
                                                                            andSubtitlePath:subtitle
                                                                             withTypeServer:serverType
                                                                                   withName:nameFilm
                                                                              withEpisodeId:epObject.episodeId
                                                                                 withFilmId:filmId
                                                                               withDuration:lastDuration
                                                                                 withSeason:epObject.id_season];

[[AppDelegate shareInstance].currentVisibleController presentViewController:[AppDelegate shareInstance].player animated:NO completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: Can you add a backtrace? When your app crashes, type bt in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You may well be getting the error because of notifications being sent to a removed controller object as @Bannings says. Nevertheless, I have a couple of other suggestions that will improve your code (and I am fairly sure will remove the error).

Firstly, the documentation says that you should register for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` and use the `loadState` method to determine when the movie is ready to start playing. I strongly suggest that you do that.

Secondly, you are instantiating a `MPMoviePlayerController` every time your view appears. I would suggest that you create a single `AFPlayerViewController` and a single `MPMoviePlayerController`. Present the same `AFPPlayerViewController` whenever you wish to play another movie.

When you first instantiate the `MPMoviePlayerController`, you will need a a URL, for its `init` method, but subsequent movies can be started using the `contentURL` property of `MPMoviePlayerController`

A side advantage of my suggestion is that it will be very easy for a user to pause a movie, go to a different view, and then quickly resume when they return to the movie view.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the `removeNotification` if you try and watch something else? try to add `viewDidDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self removeNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the real problem here: you should be using `MPMoviePlayerController` not `MPMoviewPlayerViewController`. Make that change, and see if the crash disappears. My suggestion about `loadState` should be followed too.

Comment: Yes, I had tried with MPMoviePlayerController. But I still receive that message: [MPMoviePlayerController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance. I think, my MPMoviewPlayerController does not release.